# Strongly typed object output with same keys as input

Tags: typescript

I want to write a function that returns several configuration settings from a settings store. Settings can be of several types, some have parameters, some hold strings, some hold arrays like so:

```js
type StringSetting = 'outputPath' | 'fileName'
type StringSettingWithParam = 'emailAddress' | 'homeDirectory'
type ArrayOfStringsSetting = 'inputPaths'
```

I want to fetch several settings at once, the function implementation is not a problem, but I can't find a way to strongly type the function:

Example parameter to the function:

```js
{
  a: {setting: 'outputPath'},
  b: {setting: 'emailAddress', param: 'userA'},
  c: {setting: 'inputPaths'}
}
```

Expected return value

```js
{
  a: '/home/user', // string
  b: 'foo@bar.com', // string
  c: ['/usr/var/output', '/home/user/output'] // string[]
}
```

In other words, the output type should have the same keys as the input type, the output values should be dependent on the input values

I thought, a good starting point would be to describe functions for each kind of input type

```js
type StringSettingProcessor = (s: {setting: StringSetting}) => string
type StringWithParamSettingProcessor = (s: { setting: StringSettingWithParam; param: string }) => string
type ArrayOfStringsSettingProcessor = (s: { setting: ArrayOfStringsSetting }) => string[]
```

Now I can combine all of those into a single type

```js
type Processors = StringSettingProcessor | StringWithParamSettingProcessor | ArrayOfStringsSettingProcessor
```

My function signature could be perhaps be something like this, but I have no idea how to correctly set the output type.

```js
function getSettings<T extends Record<string, Parameters<Processors>[0]>(settings: { [K in keyof T]: T[K] }): any {}
```

Comment: Am I right that the parameter, if any, has no effect on the type of that setting? That is, it can't be `string` if it has one parameter but `number` if it has another?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: They don't have the same type, if it was the case, the problem would be none. In effect, the return types are even more complicated, can be `string`, `string[]`, `number[]` or `Record<string,any>`

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't clear. I'm talking about the `param` used with `StringSettingWithParam`. The name of that type suggests that the resulting value will always be string, but I wanted to double-check that it didn't depend on the *value* of `param`. Assuming I'm right about that, I'm pretty sure my answer does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a mapped conditional type. First, let's describe the basic shape of your `settings` param:

```
type GetSettingsParamObject = Record<
    string,
    | { setting: StringSetting }
    | { setting: StringSettingWithParam; param: string }
    | { setting: ArrayOfStringsSetting }
>;
```

We'll use that as the `extends` clause of a generic parameter on `getSetting`:

```
function getSetting<ParamType extends GetSettingsParamObject>(
    settings: ParamType
): GetSettingsResult<ParamType> {
    // ...
}
```

So now we need to create the `GetSettingsResult` mapped type that maps those keys to their equivalent return types:

```
type GetSettingsResult<ParamType extends GetSettingsParamObject> = {
    [Key in keyof ParamType]: ParamType[Key]["setting"] extends StringSetting
        ? string
        : ParamType[Key]["setting"] extends StringSettingWithParam
        ? string
        : string[];
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcxhYwWqgXigCIB7AV2DHIAUBDYAC0KgB8iAzRAGwgDkaBbCIQDcAKFCRYCHBiw4A6oga14A-EQj8aXAIIATPfAgBnY01aF6xQQBFERgMbBi8ECPHhoO+KpAB5NjgkNGNZbDR1QhRKYFoGMzEPSQBxTDCcYxUBPwAjACsIJ3UAJUKXPQAeUSgaqGNpNAAaatrWAG86zHDUAC4pYPQunCgAXxaa9s65ND6gmSG0RWUaVX5hKDAVgT76gdHxligO4wXeqG9fALmQ9IixgD5EiWhU4FvUY1LjUk5gCqz+AAVTxQCAAD2AEGQemMUFe70yW34uQKTnu6jaBwA2gBpCAgKAoKAAa3xxDYUABwMgAF0+lTPLj8TSsYQTtNUIQaaCIVCYf15hyDrUoAB+OoNVDC2r0pHUiBMkAstmnLk8yHQ2HXQYcpb0AHSmri3Y4Q1QHaSrE0sQjRJsUjIJyIYjIKCoNKnf5ykHgjX8+GnRGrFGFYD3AAUB3Z3WMstW8tEAEo+gGOZ8TD8-gzIOjMSKHC7jMRuAA6TjEVDh6MZRNiEVGYCkeCu5A-ThQGiwmjIEA20SiAvIepQIzfX7qd1vU7hvO1Gh9Y6nPokcgxOKMUbNEU5BdTbrLzTaTj6QwmMyNDZI5ekE7wHRMEZb2oOXfVmZEaLUOj0Myb0QjWsB0LYsIDLCtw1HTMSxoQCAHpYJFRCkJqAA9UUgKHECwMrSDfhLHI4IQ5DiKgNCMKLUtyxwjM8IcQiSOIsigA)

Comment: Implemented and working like a charm, many, many thanks, T.J. Crowder

Answer (score -1):

This will correctly infer keys in the return value, you have to add params etc, but this should be a good start

```js
type StringSetting = 'outputPath' | 'fileName'
type StringSettingWithParam = 'emailAddress' | 'homeDirectory'
type ArrayOfStringsSetting = 'inputPaths'

type Settings = StringSetting | StringSettingWithParam | ArrayOfStringsSetting

type GetSettingsArgs<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: { setting: Settings }
}

type GetSettingsReturnValue<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: string
}

function getSettings<T>(args: GetSettingsArgs<T>): GetSettingsReturnValue<T> {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(args).map((key) => [key, "somesettings"])) as GetSettingsReturnValue<T>
}

const settings = getSettings({
  a: { setting: "outputPath" }
})

const aSettings = settings.a;
```

Comment: This gives the wrong return type for `c` (`string` instead of `string[]`) using the OP's example settings object.

Comment: I know, but like I wrote in my post, it's a start.